# UITextField check if user typed in numeric

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

I am very new to coding, therefore sorry if this question is really silly)
I am making a program which will get users input through text field, multiply it by 2 and then return user the result.
I need to check if user typed in the UItextField a number pr if he/she typed in some text.
if it's a text then in a UILabel will appear " sorry, give me a number"
if it's a number - program will multiply it and show result in a label.

So, how can I check if the users input in UITextField is numeric?
I tried casting it to an Int but obviously I can't do magic outside Hogwarts and it didn't work(

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add the code you have, trying to converting the text to an Int is one way to check if the text is numeric.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code you already tried and follow the questioning guidelines.